# json data with lazy list

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display data that I am getting from server through json. How can I use lazylist to show that data. My current code does not work and I have no Idea why. Please help me. Modification to current code will be helpful.

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;
JSONParser jsons = new JSONParser();
UserFunctions userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
JSONArray data = null;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> inboxList;
String[] tS;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    inboxList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    List<String> t = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    List<String> im = new ArrayList<String>();

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, tS, mTitles);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(listener);

    /********************************/

    JSONObject json = userFunctions.homeData();

    Log.e("Data", json.toString());

    // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
    //Log.d("Inbox JSON: ", json.toString());

    try {
        data = json.getJSONArray("data");
        Log.d("inbox array: ", data.toString());
        // looping through All messages
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String uid = c.getString("uid");
            String name = c.getString("name");
            String success = c.getString("success");
            String profile_img = c.getString("profile_image");
            //String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put("uid", uid);
            map.put("name", name);
            map.put("success", success);
            map.put("profile_image", profile_img);

            t.add(profile_img);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            inboxList.add(map);
        }

        tS = new String[t.size()];
        t.toArray(tS);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /*******************************/
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    list.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}

public OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

private String[] mTitles = {
        "title 1", "title 2", "title 3", "title 4", "title 5", "title 6", "title 7", "title 8", "title 9", "title 10",
        "title 11", "title 12", "title 13", "title 14", "title 15", "title 16", "title 17", "title 18", "title 19", "title 20",
        "title 21", "title 22", "title 23", "title 24", "title 25", "title 26", "title 27", "title 28", "title 29", "title 30",
        "title 31", "title 32", "title 33", "title 34", "title 35", "title 36", "title 37", "title 38", "title 39", "title 40",
        "title 41", "title 42", "title 43", "title 44", "title 45", "title 46", "title 47", "title 48", "title 49", "title 50",
        "title 51", "title 52", "title 53", "title 54", "title 55", "title 56", "title 57", "title 58", "title 59", "title 60",
        "title 61", "title 62", "title 63", "title 64", "title 65", "title 66", "title 67", "title 68", "title 69", "title 70",
        "title 71", "title 72", "title 73", "title 74", "title 75", "title 76", "title 77", "title 78", "title 79", "title 80",
        "title 81", "title 82", "title 83", "title 84", "title 85", "title 86", "title 87", "title 88", "title 89", "title 90",
        "title 91", "title 92", "title 93", "title 94", "title 95", "title 96", "title 97", "title 98", "title 99", "title 100",
        "title 101", "title 102", "title 103", "title 104"
};

}
```

Here is my logcat output

```
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fedorvlasov.lazylist/com.fedorvlasov.lazylist.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245):    at com.fedorvlasov.lazylist.LazyAdapter.getCount(LazyAdapter.java:29)
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:485)
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245):    at com.fedorvlasov.lazylist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
06-30 08:49:25.210: E/AndroidRuntime(31245):    ... 11 more
```

here is my lazyadapter

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private String[] data;
private String[] titles;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d, String[] mTitles) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    titles = mTitles;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

    TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
    TextView title=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_title);
    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
    text.setText("item "+position);
    title.setText("Title: " + titles[position]);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
    return vi;
}
}
```

Comment: edit post with LazyAdapter class code because you have problem in LazyAdapter class

Comment: [Why NullPointerException ?](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/why-nullpointerexception-occures-in.html)

Comment: @imran khan i added lazylist adapter please see

Comment: @al0neevenings : String[] tS; is empty

Comment: Since lazyadapter constructor accepts strings array as parameters. And I putting data in ListArray and later I convert that ListArray to simple array and pass it to lazyadapter. I think the problem it somewhere here what I said.

Comment: @Imran Khan why is it empty? I have no idea. I am converting listarray to String tS.

Comment: see this line     `list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, tS, mTitles); when you are passing tS to LazyAdapter `

Comment: try to put  `adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, tS, mTitles);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);` after `t.toArray(tS);` line

Comment: I did what you but it is not working. It does not display anything on the screen. It also does not show any errors in logcat.

Comment: then why you are saying it's not working? now it's working but tS, mTitles arrays is emply so make sure you are getting data from service by printing size of arrays

Comment: @al0neevenings : put `Log.v("tS size",tS.size() );Log.v("mTitles  size",mTitles.size() ); Log.v("t size",t.size() );`  after `tS = new String[t.size()];` line check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is in ur adapter setting without having data u have set adapter that y exception occurs
add this line

```
adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, tS, mTitles);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

after this line

```
 t.toArray(tS);
```

and one more thing is  in ur activity first check where u have assing data in **mTitles** i don't get any code for that in ur activity

Comment: I added `adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, tS, mTitles);
list.setAdapter(adapter);` lines after `t.toArray(tS)`. But nowIt does not display anything. Secondly I also added mTitles code in my above code please see that.

Comment: and check it works or not and one more thing **mTitles** array data i think it is null bcz in ur activity not added code to set data in that array without data if u are tyring to fetch data it show an error to u like NUllPointerException

Comment: Now I added mTitles array data as well in my above code. Can see that code in my thread now?

Comment: have u check after adding code what is show update ur question too with code

Comment: Yes it did but it is not working. It does not show data on the screen.

Comment: come at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11936/android-lite for disscusion bcz we have to avoid comment here